# Pass arguments to a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

By default I cannot pass arguments to a callback function

```js
function callback() {
  alert('Hi human');
}
var x = 1, y = 2;//Pass arguments(x,y) to a callback function
document.getElementById('someelem').addEventListener('click', callback);
```

```html
<button id="someelem">Ok</button>
```

Comment: Use anonymous function and call function with params inside it, or use `.bind(params)`.

Comment: Your callback doesn't seem to ask for any arguments.  Declaring the variables x and y does not have the effect of passing them as arguments to a function.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('someelem').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    callback(x, y, e);
});
```

Another way is to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function

```
document.getElementById('someelem').addEventListener('click', callback.bind(null, x, y));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create it as an anonymous function like so:

```
var x = 1, y = 2;//Pass arguments(x,y) to a callback function

document.getElementById('someelem').addEventListener('click', function(x, y) {
   alert('Hi human');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to overcome the issue.

```js
function callback(x, y) {
  console.log(this,x,y);
}
var x = 1,
  y = 2; //Pass arguments(x,y) to a callback function
var el = document.getElementById('someelem');
el.addEventListener('click', callback.bind(el, x, y));
```

```html
<button id="someelem">OK</button>
```