# Pickup argument in function and callback with original arguments

Tags: javascript

How can I pass a callback to a function and that function to call the callback with the original arguments the `callee` needs (but substitute first argument with result) ?

I have this example:

```
this.createImage: function(base64, callback) {
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = base64;
 img.onLoad = function() {
  callback(this); // I also want to pass position here (this + arbitrary number of arguments)
 }
} 

this.addToCanvas: function(item, position) {

  if(!this.isImage(item)) { // assume `isImage()` check if item is Image, & skips if true 
    var item = this.createImage(item, this.addToCanvas);
    return;
  }

  item.position = position;
  // Supposedly here I am certain that image is an Image() and not a 
  // base64 string
}
```

So basically I'm wondering how can I have `createImage` to callback `addToCanvas` but instead with the original `position` passed but `item` taking the place of the loaded `img`.

---

The idea here is to be able to call `addToCanvas()` with either an `Image` or a `base64 String` and still be able to convert internally *if* needed.

However I'd like to still be able to reuse `createImage()` with other functions that need to be called back with another(arbitrary) number of arguments. I'm wondering if it's possible not to *couple* the above functions together.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want.  Do you want to call `createImage()` with a bunch of arguments (and indeterminate number) and have the arguments after the first two be sent to the callback?   I also fail to see how `addToCanvas()` has any connection to `createImage()`.  As you show them above, then aren't related at all (neither one calls the other).

Comment: @jfriend00 I'd like to call `addToCanvas()` and if `item` is not an Image, convert it using `createImage()` and callback passing the original `position` argument with it. - Second part: Ideally I should be able to call `createImage()` from other functions and have it call them back with their original arguments so it can be reused. Makes more sense?

Comment: The trouble you'll have is that if the conversion is needed, the ultimate `onLoad` handler will be called asynchronously, so the `item.position = position` will have already run. So basically, you need to have `addToCanvas()` receive a callback that either gets wrapped in another function and passed when the conversion is needed, or gets called immediately when not.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yikes, editing now - they're related now, was a typo

Comment: @squint probably, care to wrap it into an answer and enlighten me?

Comment: Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+pass+arguments+to+callback) ? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35010357/218196) seems to be what you want.

Comment: Why not just return `img` from `this.createImage()`, and then set `img.onLoad()` in the calling function (`this.addToCanvas()`, in this example).

Comment: @pzp That would couple them together, thus making `createImage()` non-reusable which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: I guess I was assuming that the caller needs a result from `.addToCanvas`. If not, it's a little simpler. Basically will the caller possibly need to wait for the potential `onLoad` before continuing, or is that not needed?

Comment: That's exactly what this does, though! It let's you reuse the logic in `createImage()` that converts `base64` into an image, and lets the calling function set the handler for when it loads, as the calling functions evidently have very diverse requirements.

Comment: @pzp Err, the control structure would be a bit complex in `addItem()` in that case. There would be other cases I'd like to handle there and your solution would necessitate me wrapping the rest of the `addItem()` instructions in `img.onLoad()`, no?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: ...also, how does `this.isImage()` work? I don't see anything in your code that intends to update `this` to indicate that we now have a newly created image.

Comment: @squint Assume it returns `true` if `Image`, `false` if base64 string. I didn't include that function but I noted in the code comments about this.

Comment: The immediate boolean return does make it simpler. But what I mean is that you're passing the same `addToCanvas` function as the callback, but nothing changes on `this` that would indicate that the new call indeed has an image. Just want to make sure that it's clear that `this` does need to be updated to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: @squint  `callback(this)`, <- `this` is referring to the loaded image I guess..

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: Maybe I'm confused, but I thought `item` was the (potential) image. Doesn't matter. I'll add a little extra code just to make it clear.

Comment: ...actually, valid syntax would be good too. I assume you mean `this.createImage = function(base64, callback) {...` and so on.

Comment: Of course, I'm blatantly chopping code away to make it easier to digest, so no worries I got this covered :)

Comment: I missed that you were passing `item` to `isImage`. Makes more sense. However, "valid" is always better than "shorter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest just using a local function.

If the data is already an image, you just call the local function immediately that processes it.  If it's not already an image, you convert it to an image and then call the local function from the callback.

Because the local function has access to all the arguments passed to the original function call, this solves that part of your issue without having to do any special argument passing.  It's also one of the great features of Javascript (that functions have access to all their parent arguments):

```
this.createImage = function (base64, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onLoad = function () {
        callback(img);
    }
    img.src = base64;
}

this.addToCanvas = function (item, position) {

    function addIt(img) {
        // we know that img is an actual image here so you can process it now
        img.position = position;

        // other processing of the image here ...
    }

    if (!this.isImage(item)) {
        // have to make it an image before addIt
        this.createImage(item, addIt);
    } else {
        // already an image, can call addIt now
        addIt(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: fits the bill :) - you mean't `this.createImage(item, addIt)` instead of `this.createImage(item, doIt)`, no?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - yes, that was a typo.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - I also cleaned up some things related to the newly created image.  Since it is passed to the callback from `createImage()`, I made `addIt()` work that way to align.

Comment: @jfriend00: Should probably correct his invalid function syntax. I assume he meant `this.createImage = function(base64, callback) {...` and same for the other. But +1

Comment: The weird thing is that I've accidentally written invalid function code like that a bunch of times. Almost feels like it could've been a valid function syntax.

Comment: I've been getting to grips with ES6 Classes recently so I'm a bit disoriented when dashing through it. oh well..

Comment: @jfriend00: Except that the trailing block could be used to disambiguate, since the syntax fails at that point. However, it would be weird for sure, hence the *"almost feels like"*. :)

Comment: @squint - Yeah, I suppose.  Except a block of code is allowed in that position after a function call.  Not a whole lot of point to it unless using block scope variables, but it is allowed.

Comment: @jfriend00: I think a semicolon is required to separate the statements. `this.foo(a, b) { console.log("foobar'); }` doesn't run as is. However, ASI would insert one if there was a line break before the `{`. Don't get me wrong, it would be really bad syntax, IMO, but somehow it feels natural when typing it.

Comment: @squint - Yeah, you're right a semicolon is required to get past the parser if on the same line.

Comment: if `callback(img) ` works, that would make it more readable. and I would wrap `addIt` inside `else` into a zero `setTimeout` to make the execution order of the 2 branches more similar thus easier to reason about when debugging...

Comment: I like the change to `callback(img)`.  I don't really see the reason to add the `setTimeout()`.  There's no return value from `addToCanvas()` either way.  If it had a completion callback itself, I would agree that both paths should be async, but without that, I don't see any advantage to adding the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Made several code cleanup changes.  One important one is to set `.src` after setting `.onload` handler to avoid cache bugs in some versions of IE.

Comment: @jfriend00 what about the return value? if assigning `img.position` didn't have any browser reflow side effects, that would be a pretty useless callback. it might be a valid use case to not use `setTimeout` to reduce the number of repaints if the item is already an `Image`, but if that is the case, the `img.position` might be better set even before parsing the base64 string (if possible)

Comment: @Aprillion - The OP doesn't show the full purpose of this code.  Without that, it's really hard to evaluate whether a `setTimeout()` should be added or not. I don't yet see a reason for it, but that doesn't mean there isn't a reason.  I'm not sure what you mean by your comment about return value?  For context here, I'm really just trying to show the local function concept to solve the original problem.  The OP's code is pseudo-code and only showing a piece of the operation so I can't really comment on overall code improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking for **partial argument application**. This is a functional programming technique: In pure JavaScript, you'd do it like this:

```
var that = this; // necessary because this has another vaue inside the wrapper function
var item = this.createImage(item, function(x) {
   return that.addToCanvas(x, position)
});

// here you are passing a wrapper function, that 'waits' for an x to be passed in order to call finally addToCanvas, with x and position.

img.onLoad = function() {
  callback(this);  // this goes into the above's x
}
```

---

The same thing using a functional library like underscore.js would look more elegantly as followed:

```
var item = this.createImage(item, _.partial(this.addToCanvas, _, position));
```